# How to proxy angular app with nginx on a rails box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, nginx

I have one domain and two servers, one running rails one angular js.

The domain name points to the box running rails.

I want to use a path as a namespace to serve up my angular site via proxy_pass.

For example..

`mydomain.com/#/admin` or `mydomain.com/admin` <-- This should proxy_pass to the angular server

`mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com/anything-except-admin` <-- this should serve up rails content

I've tried may things to get this to work, but the problems I run into are:

**Problem 1**

Angular uses the '#' symbol at the root path. Rails will always interpret the '#' symbol as root also.

So any thing served from `mydomain.com/#/` is interpreted by rails as `mydomain.com/`

This means that `mydomain.com/#/admin` is considered `mydomain.com/`

But angular needs the '#' symbol, so the angular app will not be found in this case.

**Problem 2**

As an attempt to resolve the first problem, there is a way in angular to avoid using the '#' symbol.

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

While this does in part solve the first problem, it introduces another. For instance:

`mydomain.com/admin` <-- this works to serve up the angular app

Once here, as I navigate the angular app as a user would in the browser, all is fine. But if I refresh the page, I get a 404 or an nginx error depending on how I've setup the proxy_pass

For example, if I navigated here by clicking around the angular app:

`mydomain.com/admin/dashboard` then I refresh the page, it is interpreted as a new GET request to that path, and I could not get the proxy_pass to pass the request to angular, so it always hit the rails app. Since there is no route for this path in rails I get a 404.

**Problem 3**

Finally, it's been proposed to use custom subdomains. Unfortunately I can't because this app requires wildcard subdomains as part of the multi-tenant authentication. This is business rule that can't be changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's all easy manageable by nginx [locations](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) but your question isn't enough clear for me to help you with building right configuration for your case. As I see, you need to handle `/admin` and `/#/admin` one way and anything else another way, plus you want to use custom subdomains for these two handlers, is it correct?

Comment: Hi @DmitryVerkhoturov, I need wildcard subdomains, and I want the path to have admin in it. It could be /admin./#/ or /#/admin -- whatever is easer.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like that:

```
server {
    # implemented by default, change if you need different ip or port
    # listen *:80 | *:8000;

    # same as server_name  yoursite.com  www.yoursite.com  *.yoursite.com;
    server_name .yoursite.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @ruby;
    }

    location ~ ^/(\#/)?(admin) {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @angular;
    }

# there must be configured @ruby and @angular locations
<...>
}
```

Here is documentation on [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization) and [locations](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), please give it a try and tell us if there will be any problems.
For debugging `locations` and whole configuration your best friends are `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.