# How to configure Nginx to serve both Rails app and Angular on same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, nginx

I'd like to use Nginx to serve both my Rails (using passenger) and an Angular front end.

Basically, all requests that goes to `/` should be directed to Rails and every request that goes to `/admin/*` should be redirected to a Angular App.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520005/how-to-proxy-angular-app-with-nginx-on-a-rails-box) that would theoretically be exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately Dmitry's answer is a bit vague for someone (like me) who doesn't know much (next to nothing) about Nginx.

**EDIT: Here's the Nginx configuration that I have tried:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name 178.62.92.199;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env development;
    root /var/www/netturing/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location ~ ^/admin/ {
            proxy_pass http: /var/www/client/admin;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http: /var/www/netturing/public;
    }

}
```

Could someone extend the answer a bit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) it's a better tool to do this.

But I have some rails apps in [standalone passenger server](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html) with nginx in front.

My suggested nginx config:

```
server {

  # some config directives
  ...

  # Al turrón !

  # Angular App
  location ~ ^/admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://<URI TO ANGULAR APP>;
  }

  # Rails App
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://<URI TO RAILS APP>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I've updated my question with a code snippet.

Comment: In essence, the question it's better formuled and detailed and the question it's exactly the same in both cases with a little bit differences.

Comment: I agree the questions are pretty much the same, however I did not understand the answer, nor the code snippet given as answer. In such case, what would you have me do?

Comment: Dmitry explain rightly, you must declare locations for `@ruby` and `@angular`, but do `try_files` first.

Comment: Your `location` sections appear a little wrong. you must configure the proxy section to app server.